# Dealing with permissions issues on shared computer

Tags: ruby, git, bundler, file-permissions

I am creating a shared computer (Mac) that can be shared between multiple QA Testers to run Appium tests.  These testers should be able to log into the computer using their credentials and execute a script that will run `git checkout master`, `git pull`, and `bundle update`.   We have Windows VM's that following a similar process for executing selenium browser automation, but due to MacOS's file permissions this process becomes harder.  When one user runs a `bundle update` or `git pull` the files that are created are owned by that user (stored under `/Users/Shared`).  When a 2nd user logs in and runs those commands, he will often get a permission denied message because he doesn't own the files that are being edited.  Is there a decent way around this?  I know I can run `chmod -R go=rwx /Users/Shared/..` after performing each command, but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution that will scale well over time.

Comment: Put your git repository in shared mode. Set the sgid sticky bit on your directories. Use https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite as a server. A lot depends on your actual workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works on macs but on a linux box you can use `setgid` on the directory so that the files that are created inside will have that gid set up.... if all those users share that same group, they will be able to work on it without having to change permissions.

Comment: I think macOS uses the BSD behavior of inheriting the group by default and setting the setgid bit enables the SysV/Linux behavior of using the user's primary group.